# Set the y-axis to scale in a Seaborn heat map

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I currently have a dataframe, df:

```
In  [1]: df
Out [1]:

   one        two
      1.5    11.22
        2    15.36
      2.5    11
      3.3    12.5
      3.5    14.78
        5    9
      6.2    26.14
```

I used this code to get a heat map:

```
In [2]:

plt.figure(figsize=(30, 7))
plt.title('Test')
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df, annot=True,)
plt.xlabel('Test')
ax.invert_yaxis()

value = 6
index = np.abs(df.index - value).argmin()
ax.axhline(index + .5, ls='--')
print(index)

Out [2]:
```

[image: Out [2] Result]

I am looking for the y-axis, instead, to automatically scale and plot the df[2] values in their respective positions on the full axis. For example, there should be a clear empty space between 3.5 and 5.0 as there aren’t any values - I want the values in between on the y-axis with 0 value against them.

Comment: Could you explain what you want from this visualisation? Looks like you are looking for something else, not heatmap. Because Heatmap is supposed to have the same amount of rows and columns as your data and show how different values are with colours. So you can't add additional rows to show that there are no data between some values and this visualisation is not about that. I can try to help you find what you need, if you like.

Comment: Heatmaps do not have a continues axis. the ticks are discreate locations that are 0 indexed, where your values are just labels. If it's not in your data, then it's not going to be on the heatmap. Additionally, seems like this should be a barplot, not a heatmap.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with a bar plot instead:

```
plt.bar(df['one'], df['two'], color=list('rgb'), width=0.2, alpha=0.4)
```

[image]